# Как отправить заголовок формы обратной связи на почту?

Tags: email, php, html

Есть формы обратной связи, надо, чтобы заголовок формы пришел на почту. Как это можно сделать?
Вот пример html кода формы обратной связи:

```
    <div class="header_modal"><p>Получите <span>бесплатный</span><br /> экспресс-аудит вашего сайта</p></div>
```

Comment: Когда вы учились ездить на велосипеде, родители вам давали вместо велосипеда стул и говорили крути воображаемые педали, так ты научишься ездить? Я это к тому, что код, который вы дам дали, абсолютно бесполезен для нас. Показывайте код, который обрабатывает форму.

Answer (score 2):

```
mail("адрес@получателя.ком", "Тема", "Сообщение",
 "From: Вася Пупкин <Кто@отправил.ком>\r\n"  //от кого
."Reply-To: кому@отвечать.ком\r\n"); //кому отвечать
```